# Connecting Wifi bee with Xbee USB adapter

Tags: wifi, usb

I started to follow "Get started with the Wifi Bee" tutorial in [Wifi bee v1.0 wiki page](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/WiFi_Bee_V1.0_%28SKU%3aTEL0067%29). 
I am using Xbee USB adapter v2.0,Wifi Bee-RN-XV,mini USB cable as listed in **Tools needed**.
When i conneted the Xbee USB adapter v2 to my computer via mini USB cable Wifi bee didn't light up (but USB adapter did light up). Then i followed all the steps till number 4, which is " Send AT command $$$ to the wifi Bee and it will reply "CMD" to indicate that it enter the command mode properly". When i sent command, it didn't reply anything. I typed other commands like **show net** and  **scan**, it didn't reply either.

When i tried **Arduino Server example** in the wiki page, Wifi bee lighted up. But it gave me some strange ip address with port 200, and when i entered that ip address to my browser address, browser couldn't find the page.

So my question is does Xbee Usb adapter need some extra power sources? Or it just doesn't fit with Wifi Bee? I don't think the problem is with usb cable, 'cause my computer found the device.

Comment: can you ping that ip address? what OS are you using?